# How to parametrize function calls in dplyr 0.7?

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang

The release of dplyr 0.7 includes a [major overhaul](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) of programming with dplyr. I read this document carefully, and I am trying to understand how it will impact my use of dplyr.

Here is a common idiom I use when building reporting and aggregation functions with dplyr:

```
my_report <- function(data, grouping_vars) {
  data %>%
    group_by_(.dots=grouping_vars) %>%
    summarize(x_mean=mean(x), x_median=median(x), ...)
}
```

Here, `grouping_vars` is a vector of strings.

I like this idiom because I can pass in string vectors from other places, say a file or a Shiny app's reactive UI, but it's also not too bad for interactive work either.

However, in the new [programming with dplyr vignette](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html), I see no examples of how something like this can be done with the new dplyr. I only see examples of how passing strings is no longer the correct approach, and I have to use quosures instead.

I'm happy to adopt quosures, but how exactly do I get from strings to the quosures expected by dplyr here? It doesn't seem feasible to expect the entire R ecosystem to provide quosures to dplyr - lots of times we're going to get strings and they'll have to be converted.

Here is an example showing what you're now supposed to do, and how my old idiom doesn't work:

```
library(dplyr)
grouping_vars <- quo(am)
mtcars %>%
  group_by(!!grouping_vars) %>%
  summarise(mean_cyl=mean(cyl))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>      am mean_cyl
#>   <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1     0 6.947368
#> 2     1 5.076923

grouping_vars <- "am"
mtcars %>%
  group_by(!!grouping_vars) %>%
  summarise(mean_cyl=mean(cyl))
#> # A tibble: 1 × 2
#>   `"am"` mean_cyl
#>    <chr>    <dbl>
#> 1     am   6.1875
```

Comment: It's easier to help if you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data that can be used to test possible solutions.

Comment: @MrFlick I just tried setting one up, but in the process I found I couldn't even get the quosure-based example to work. So I filed a github issue https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2661

Comment: Got a response and updated my post accordingly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`dplyr` will have a specialized group_by function `group_by_at` to deal with multiple grouping variables. It would be much easier to use the new member of the `_at` family:

```
# using the pre-release 0.6.0

cols <- c("am","gear")

mtcars %>%
    group_by_at(.vars = cols) %>%
    summarise(mean_cyl=mean(cyl))

# Source: local data frame [4 x 3]
# Groups: am [?]
# 
# am  gear mean_cyl
# <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1     0     3 7.466667
# 2     0     4 5.000000
# 3     1     4 4.500000
# 4     1     5 6.000000
```

The `.vars` argument accepts both character/numeric vector or column names generated by `vars`:

> .vars
>
> A list of columns generated by vars(), or a character vector of
> column names, or a numeric vector of column positions.

Comment: Switching my checkmark since this looks like it will be the standard way going forward.

Answer (score 11):

Here's the quick and dirty reference I wrote for myself.

```
# install.packages("rlang")
library(tidyverse)

dat <- data.frame(cat = sample(LETTERS[1:2], 50, replace = TRUE),
                  cat2 = sample(LETTERS[3:4], 50, replace = TRUE),
                  value = rnorm(50))
```

#### Representing column names with strings

Convert strings to symbol objects using `rlang::sym` and `rlang::syms`.

```
summ_var <- "value"
group_vars <- c("cat", "cat2")

summ_sym <- rlang::sym(summ_var)  # capture a single symbol
group_syms <- rlang::syms(group_vars)  # creates list of symbols

dat %>%
  group_by(!!!group_syms) %>%  # splice list of symbols into a function call
  summarize(summ = sum(!!summ_sym)) # slice single symbol into call
```

If you use `!!` or `!!!` outside of `dplyr` functions you will get an error.

The usage of `rlang::sym` and `rlang::syms` is identical inside functions.

```
summarize_by <- function(df, summ_var, group_vars) {

  summ_sym <- rlang::sym(summ_var)
  group_syms <- rlang::syms(group_vars)

  df %>%
    group_by(!!!group_syms) %>%
    summarize(summ = sum(!!summ_sym))
}
```

We can then call `summarize_by` with string arguments.

```
summarize_by(dat, "value", c("cat", "cat2"))
```

#### Using non-standard evaluation for column/variable names

```
summ_quo <- quo(value)  # capture a single variable for NSE
group_quos <- quos(cat, cat2)  # capture list of variables for NSE

dat %>%
  group_by(!!!group_quos) %>%  # use !!! with both quos and rlang::syms
  summarize(summ = sum(!!summ_quo))  # use !! both quo and rlang::sym
```

#### Inside functions use `enquo` rather than `quo`. `quos` is okay though!?

```
summarize_by <- function(df, summ_var, ...) {

  summ_quo <- enquo(summ_var)  # can only capture a single value!
  group_quos <- quos(...)  # captures multiple values, also inside functions!?

  df %>%
    group_by(!!!group_quos) %>%
    summarize(summ = sum(!!summ_quo))
}
```

And then our function call is

```
summarize_by(dat, value, cat, cat2)
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to group by possibly more than one column, you can use `quos`

```
grouping_vars <- quos(am, gear)
mtcars %>%
  group_by(!!!grouping_vars) %>%
  summarise(mean_cyl=mean(cyl))
#      am  gear mean_cyl
#   <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1     0     3 7.466667
# 2     0     4 5.000000
# 3     1     4 4.500000
# 4     1     5 6.000000
```

Right now, it doesn't seem like there's a great way to turn strings into quos. Here's one way that does work though

```
cols <- c("am","gear")
grouping_vars <- rlang::parse_quosures(paste(cols, collapse=";"))
mtcars %>%
  group_by(!!!grouping_vars) %>%
  summarise(mean_cyl=mean(cyl))
#      am  gear mean_cyl
#   <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1     0     3 7.466667
# 2     0     4 5.000000
# 3     1     4 4.500000
# 4     1     5 6.000000
```

Comment: @joran on my end, your version without `rlang::parse_quosures` yields a groupby with only `am`, not `am` and `gear` together. Is it different for you?

Comment: @Paul No, you're both right, I wasn't looking carefully.

Comment: @MrFlick this wouldn't be that bad if the parse_quosures boilerplate were wrapped in a function: `as_quosure <- function(strs) rlang::parse_quosures(paste(strs, collapse=";"))`. Then you can just do `group_by(!!!as_quosure(cols))`

Comment: @Paul Or I just wish `rlang::parse_quosures` could take a proper vector rather than having to collapse. I'd be surprised if there weren't a good convenience function forthcoming

Comment: @Paul Indeed, as I was wrapping my head around this I was just thinking that this new method seems _awfully_ targeted at writing functions that take bare column names as arguments. Feels oddly focused on writing _interactive_ functions rather than functions generally.

Comment: What I liked about the old dplyr function was that they translated the NSE versions to SE versions which are much easier to work with/program against. This new version seems to go all-in on non-standard craziness.

Comment: @joran MrFlick That's what I thought at first too, but I think hadley's genius idea is that the robustness of the new NSE/quosure framework is supposed to make it easy to "use NSE for SE". This example is a good initial kick of the wheels - hopefully it will continue to hold up. I'm going to raise this in a github issue.

Comment: @Paul I was so annoyed with my answer that I did the same: https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2662

Comment: `syms` may be helpful, e.g. `(function(data, ...){
    data %>% 
        group_by(!!!rlang::syms(list(...))) %>%
        summarize(mpg = mean(mpg))
})(mtcars, 'cyl', 'am')`

Comment: @alistaire. Yeah, that's what Hadley pointed out on the github issue. But I think `group_by_at` is a "better" solution.

Comment: Oops, clicked too late. I still can't find one that goes straight from dots of strings to quosures/symbols without `list`, though.