# Converting a quoted list into a list of quoted expressions for dplyr::filter

Tags: r, dplyr, non-standard-evaluation, quosure

I am writing a function that combines a `dplyr::filter` step (which I want to parametrize) before doing some other stuff.  I want provide a default argument for the filtering criteria that can be overridden.  This precludes passing the filtering arguments in with `...`  One attempt, would be the following:

```r
library(rlang)
library(dplyr)
filter_and_stuff1 = function(tbl, filter_args = list(mpg > 33, gear == 4), arg3, arg4){
    as_expr = enexpr(filter_args)
    sub_tbl = filter(tbl, !!!as_expr)
    # do some other things with sub_tbl, arg3 and arg4
    sub_tbl
}
```

But

```r
filter_and_stuff1(mtcars)
Error: Argument 2 filter condition does not evaluate to a logical vector
```

It seems that the comma separation creates a problem.  Looking inside dplyr's code, it's handled with a call to the internal function  `quo_reduce`, which seems to splice together the comma separated values with `&`. I don't understand how to do this without use of `...`

TLDR: How can I programmatically pass a set of arguments to dplyr::filter that includes a default expression?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51005956/3777396

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that, with the way you're using it, `enexpr` also captures the call to `list`,
whereas using the ellipsis already separates each expression into different elements of a list:

```
library(rlang)

foo <- function(x) {
    enexpr(x)
}

foo(list(a, b, c))
# list(a, b, c)

bar <- function(...) {
    enexprs(...)
}

bar(a, b, c)
# [[1]]
# a
# 
# [[2]]
# b
# 
# [[3]]
# c
```

To do what you want, you can use `call_args` to extract each expression from what was given to `list`:

```
baz <- function(x) {
    as_expr <- enexpr(x)
    # expr just to show
    expr(filter(!!!call_args(as_expr)))
}

baz(list(a == 1, b < 2))
# filter(a == 1, b < 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I drop the requirement that multiple arguments to `filter` can be comma-separated, this works:

```
filter_and_stuff2 = function(tbl, filter_args = mpg > 33 & gear == 4, arg3, arg4){
    filter(tbl, !!enexpr(filter_args))
}

> filter_and_stuff2(mtcars)
   mpg cyl disp hp drat    wt qsec vs am gear carb gear4
1 33.9   4 71.1 65 4.22 1.835 19.9  1  1    4    1  TRUE
```