# If/else condition in dplyr 0.7 function

Tags: r, function, if-statement, dplyr

I'd like to make a simple if/else condition in a dplyr function. I've looked at some helpful posts (e.g., [How to parametrize function calls in dplyr 0.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43415475/how-to-parametrize-function-calls-in-dplyr-0-7?rq=1)), but am still running into trouble.

Below is a toy example that works when I call the function *without* the grouping variable. The function then fails with the grouping variable.

```
# example dataset
test <- tibble(
  A = c(1:5,1:5),
  B = c(1,2,1,2,3,3,3,3,3,3),
  C = c(1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,4,3)
)

# begin function, set default for group var to NULL.
prop_tab <- function(df, column, group = NULL) {

  col_name <- enquo(column)
  group_name <- enquo(group)

  # if group_by var is NOT null, then...
  if(!is.null(group)) {
      temp <- df %>%
        select(!!col_name, !!group_name) %>% 
        group_by(!!group_name) %>% 
        summarise(Percentages = 100 * length(!!col_name) / nrow(df))

  } else {
  # if group_by var is null, then...
      temp <- df %>%
        select(!!col_name) %>% 
        group_by(col_name = !!col_name) %>% 
        summarise(Percentages = 100 * length(!!col_name) / nrow(df)) 

  }

  temp
}

test %>% prop_tab(column = C)  # works

test %>% prop_tab(column = A, group = B)  # fails
# Error in prop_tab(., column = A, group = B) : object 'B' not found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that when you supply unquoted arguments, `is.null` doesn't know what to do with it. So this code tries to check whether object `B` is null and errors because `B` does not exist in that scope. Instead, you can use `missing()` to check whether an argument was supplied to the function, like so. There may be a cleaner way but this at least works, as you can see at the bottom.

```r
library(tidyverse)
test <- tibble(
  A = c(1:5,1:5),
  B = c(1,2,1,2,3,3,3,3,3,3),
  C = c(1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,4,3)
)

# begin function, set default for group var to NULL.
prop_tab <- function(df, column, group) {

  col_name <- enquo(column)
  group_name <- enquo(group)

  # if group_by var is not supplied, then:
  if(!missing(group)) {
    temp <- df %>%
      select(!!col_name, !!group_name) %>%
    group_by(!!group_name) %>%
    summarise(Percentages = 100 * length(!!col_name) / nrow(df))

  } else {
    # if group_by var is null, then...
    temp <- df %>%
      select(!!col_name) %>% 
      group_by(col_name = !!col_name) %>% 
      summarise(Percentages = 100 * length(!!col_name) / nrow(df)) 

  }

  temp
}

test %>% prop_tab(column = C)  # works
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>   col_name Percentages
#>      <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1        1          40
#> 2        2          10
#> 3        3          20
#> 4        4          20
#> 5        5          10

test %>% prop_tab(column = A, group = B)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>       B Percentages
#>   <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1     1          20
#> 2     2          20
#> 3     3          60
```

Created on 2018-06-29 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: beat you to it ;)

Comment: I don't think that's accurate to say "non tidyverse functions don't know what to do with them". NSE was there before `tidyverse`

Comment: yeah that's fair, changed to reflect that

Answer (score 2):

You can use `missing` instead of `is.null`, so your argument won't be evaluated (that's what cause the error):

```
prop_tab <- function(df, column, group = NULL) {

  col_name <- enquo(column)
  group_name <- enquo(group)

  # if group_by var is NOT null, then...
  if(!missing(group)) {
    temp <- df %>%
      select(!!col_name, !!group_name) %>% 
      group_by(!!group_name) %>% 
      summarise(Percentages = 100 * length(!!col_name) / nrow(df))

  } else {
    # if group_by var is null, then...
    temp <- df %>%
      select(!!col_name) %>% 
      group_by(col_name = !!col_name) %>% 
      summarise(Percentages = 100 * length(!!col_name) / nrow(df)) 

  }

  temp
}

test %>% prop_tab(column = C) 
# example dataset
# # A tibble: 5 x 2
#   col_name Percentages
#      <dbl>       <dbl>
# 1        1          40
# 2        2          10
# 3        3          20
# 4        4          20
# 5        5          10

test %>% prop_tab(column = A, group = B)
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#       B Percentages
#   <dbl>       <dbl>
# 1     1          20
# 2     2          20
# 3     3          60
```

You can also use `length(substitute(group))` instead of `!missing(group)`, it'll be more robust as it won't fail in the unlikely case where someone fills explicitely the group argument with `NULL` (the former option will crash in this case).

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to check on the "group_name" instead of the 'group'

```
prop_tab <- function(df, column, group = NULL) {

  col_name <- enquo(column)
  group_name <- enquo(group)

  # if group_by var is NOT null, then...
  if(as.character(group_name)[2] != "NULL") {
      temp <- df %>%
        select(!!col_name, !!group_name) %>% 
        group_by(!!group_name) %>% 
        summarise(Percentages = 100 * length(!!col_name) / nrow(df))

  } else {
  # if group_by var is null, then...
      temp <- df %>%
        select(!!col_name) %>% 
        group_by(col_name = !!col_name) %>% 
        summarise(Percentages = 100 * length(!!col_name) / nrow(df)) 

  }

  temp
}
```

-checking

```
prop_tab(test, column = C, group = B)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#<     B Percentages
# <dbl>       <dbl>
#1     1          20
#2     2          20
#3     3          60  



prop_tab(test, column = C)
# A tibble: 5 x 2
#  col_name Percentages
#     <dbl>       <dbl>
#1        1          40
#2        2          10
#3        3          20
#4        4          20
#5        5          10
```